# Card generator game printing in a column, not a row

Tags: python

```
#-*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
#spade=u"\u2660"
#heart=u"\u2665"
#diamond=u"\u2666"
#clubs=u"\u2663"
import random
print 'Welcome to SANDCRAB. This is your deck of cards.'
seg1='''_________'''
seg2='''|       |'''
seg3a="|  Ace  |"
seg32="|   2   |"
seg33="|   3   |"
seg34="|   4   |"
seg35="|   5   |"
seg36="|   6   |"
seg37="|   7   |"
seg38="|   8   |"
seg39="|   9   |"
seg310="|  10   |"
seg3jack="|  Jack |"
seg3queen="| Queen |"
seg3king="|  King |"
seg4='''|  of   |'''
seg5s="| Spade |\n|♠♠♠♠♠♠♠|"
seg5h="| Heart |\n|♥♥♥♥♥♥♥|"
seg5c="| Clubs |\n|♣♣♣♣♣♣♣|"
seg5d="|Diamond|\n|♦♦♦♦♦♦♦|"
seg6='''|       |'''
seg7='''|_______|'''
a=[seg3a,seg32,seg33,seg34,seg35,seg36,seg37,seg38,seg39,seg310,seg3jack,seg3queen,seg3king]
b=[seg5s,seg5h,seg5c,seg5d]
count=0
print seg1*13,'\n',
print seg2*13
print "".join([random.choice(a)for i in range(13)])
print seg4*13
pr= "\n".join([random.choice(b)for i in range(13)])
print pr
print seg7*13
```

Hello. I am trying to make a card generator which generates 13 random cards. I got it to work without using the special characters but now there are new problems. Whenever I run the program, the 'seg5' things print in a column and I can't get them to print side by side. comma doesn't work and I am not sure if I am using sys incorrectly but that doesn't work either. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're including a newline character in `seg5*` (`seg5s`, `seg5h`, ...)

The simplest fix would be to make these variables lists, without the newline element, then print each line separately.

To do this, I first changed `seg5*` to:

```
seg5s=["| Spade |", "|♠♠♠♠♠♠♠|"]
seg5h=["| Heart |", "|♥♥♥♥♥♥♥|"]
seg5c=["| Clubs |", "|♣♣♣♣♣♣♣|"]
seg5d=["|Diamond|", "|♦♦♦♦♦♦♦|"]
```

Then generated a list of indexes in 0 <= i <= 3, one for each card with:

```
suit_sels = [random.randint(0,3) for i in range(13)]
```

Then, when you want to print them, you can do it with:

```
# Print name
print "".join([b[i][0] for i in suit_sels])
# Print suit symbols
print "".join([b[i][1] for i in suit_sels])
```

Full code:

```
#-*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
#spade=u"\u2660"
#heart=u"\u2665"
#diamond=u"\u2666"
#clubs=u"\u2663"
import random
print 'Welcome to SANDCRAB. This is your deck of cards.'
seg1='''_________'''
seg2='''|       |'''
seg3a="|  Ace  |"
seg32="|   2   |"
seg33="|   3   |"
seg34="|   4   |"
seg35="|   5   |"
seg36="|   6   |"
seg37="|   7   |"
seg38="|   8   |"
seg39="|   9   |"
seg310="|  10   |"
seg3jack="|  Jack |"
seg3queen="| Queen |"
seg3king="|  King |"
seg4='''|  of   |'''
seg5s=["| Spade |", "|♠♠♠♠♠♠♠|"]
seg5h=["| Heart |", "|♥♥♥♥♥♥♥|"]
seg5c=["| Clubs |", "|♣♣♣♣♣♣♣|"]
seg5d=["|Diamond|", "|♦♦♦♦♦♦♦|"]
seg6='''|       |'''
seg7='''|_______|'''
a=[seg3a,seg32,seg33,seg34,seg35,seg36,seg37,seg38,seg39,seg310,seg3jack,seg3queen,seg3king]
b=[seg5s,seg5h,seg5c,seg5d]
count=0
print seg1*13,'\n',
print seg2*13
print "".join([random.choice(a) for i in range(13)])
print seg4*13
suit_sels = [random.randint(0,3) for i in range(13)]
# Print name
print "".join([b[i][0] for i in suit_sels])
# Print suit symbols
print "".join([b[i][1] for i in suit_sels])
print seg7*13
```

Output:

```
Welcome to SANDCRAB. This is your deck of cards.
_____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________ 
|       ||       ||       ||       ||       ||       ||       ||       ||       ||       ||       ||       ||       |
|   5   ||  10   ||  10   ||   9   ||   7   ||   6   ||   6   ||  Ace  ||   4   ||   7   ||   8   ||   2   ||  10   |
|  of   ||  of   ||  of   ||  of   ||  of   ||  of   ||  of   ||  of   ||  of   ||  of   ||  of   ||  of   ||  of   |
| Clubs || Heart || Heart || Clubs || Heart || Spade || Clubs || Spade || Heart || Clubs || Clubs || Heart ||Diamond|
|♣♣♣♣♣♣♣||♥♥♥♥♥♥♥||♥♥♥♥♥♥♥||♣♣♣♣♣♣♣||♥♥♥♥♥♥♥||♠♠♠♠♠♠♠||♣♣♣♣♣♣♣||♠♠♠♠♠♠♠||♥♥♥♥♥♥♥||♣♣♣♣♣♣♣||♣♣♣♣♣♣♣||♥♥♥♥♥♥♥||♦♦♦♦♦♦♦|
|_______||_______||_______||_______||_______||_______||_______||_______||_______||_______||_______||_______||_______|
```

Its worth noting that you could simplify this code quite a bit, and cut down the number of variables you were using by using of lists and generating the card "number" line programmatically, for example:

```
#-*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import random

NUM_CARDS = 13
CARD_WIDTH = 8
SUITS = [('Spades', '♠'), ('Hearts', '♥'), ('Clubs', '♣'), ('Diamonds', '♦')]
NAMES = {11: 'Jack', 12: 'Queen', 13: 'King', 14: 'Ace'}

def get_card_name(n):  return NAMES.get(n, "%2d" % n)
def card_row(text=''): return "|" + text.center(CARD_WIDTH) + "|"

# Generate card output
cards = [list() for _ in range(7)]
for _ in range(NUM_CARDS):
    cv = random.randint(2,14)   # Card Value
    cs = random.randint(0,3)    # Card Suit
    cards[0].append('_' * (CARD_WIDTH+2))
    cards[1].append(card_row(''))
    cards[2].append(card_row(get_card_name(cv)))
    cards[3].append(card_row('of'))
    cards[4].append(card_row(SUITS[cs][0]))
    cards[5].append(card_row(SUITS[cs][1]*(CARD_WIDTH)))
    cards[6].append(card_row("_" * CARD_WIDTH))

# Print card output
print 'Welcome to SANDCRAB. This is your deck of cards.'
for lst in cards:
    print ''.join(lst)
```